# How to handle shell getopts with parameter containing blank spaces

Tags: shell, getopts

I'm looking for a way to handle arguments containing blank spaces that has to be parsed 
by shell getopts command.

```
while getopts ":a:i:o:e:v:u:" arg
  do
  echo "ARG is: $arg" >> /tmp/submit.log
  case "$arg" in
  a) arg1="$OPTARG" ;;
  i) arg2="$OPTARG" ;;
  o) arg3="$OPTARG" ;;
  ...
  u) argn="$OPTARG" ;;
  -) break ;;
  \?) ;;
  *) echo "unhandled option $arg" >> /tmp/submit.log ;;
  ?) echo $usage_string
     exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
```

Now if -u has argument like "STRING WITH WHITE SPACE"
than just the first part of the string is triggered and the while loop doesn't go to the end.

many thanks.

Comment: that's not generally possible. you need to quote the arguments to your script properly, just like you did in your post.

Comment: Thanks Mat you pointed out the fault

Comment: PS: This bash getopts is a nice alternative to man getopt on Darwin.

Comment: You need to be a bit cautious when you are using $variable in script, if you have a variable like filename="some file.txt" and run a simple 'ls $filename', bash will raise an error, because the bash will run the ls command after replacing the variable. So the actual command is 'ls some file.txt' and bash will complain that it can't find 'some'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) notes, your script fragment is already correct. If you're invoking your script from a shell, you need to quote arguments properly, e.g.

```
myscript -u "string with white space"
myscript -u 'string with white space'
myscript -u string\ with\ white\ space
myscript -u string' w'ith\ "whi"te" "''space
```

Requiring these quotes is not a defect in your script, it's the way the calling shell works. All programs, scripts or otherwise, receive arguments as a *list* of strings. The quotes in the calling shell are used to sort these arguments into separate “words” (list elements). All the calls above (made from a unix shell) pass a list of three strings to the script: `$0` is the script name (`myscript`), `$1` is `-u` and `$2` is the string `string with white space`.

Comment: If Mat answer I should get his answer :-) meanwhile yours

Answer (score 42):

a trap for young players (ie me!)

beware a line like this:

```
main $@
```

what you really need is:

```
main "$@"
```

otherwise `getopts` will mince up your options into little pieces

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/70630-getopts-list-argument.html

Comment: This is a very often overlooked, but essential tip! Worked perfectly for me, thanks for the post!

Comment: Indeed, overlooked by myself and you reminded me. Thanks!

Comment: Very well reminded in this context. Thanks! +2 if I could. Also, not to use `main $*` with or without quotes. Its not the same and don't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function  getArgs {

    while getopts a:b:c:d:e: arg
    do
        case $arg in
            a) var_a=$OPTARG;;
            b) var_b=$OPTARG;;
            c) var_c=$OPTARG;;
            d) var_d=$OPTARG;;
            e) var_e=$OPTARG;;
        esac
    done
}

getArgs "$@"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).